# NodeJS for Azure CLI command: az resource show $resourceID

Tags: node.js, azure-sdk

I'm trying to figure out if resources exist in Azure by using their resource ID. The Azure CLI command would be `az resource show $resourceID`. My application is in NodeJS.

Is there some equivalent in NodeJS I can use in my application? If not, is there another way to show a resource exists (information populates) or does not exist (null fields) in NodeJS?

Ultimately want to return true (exists) or false (does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

To access Azure from your application, you can use their [SDK](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/index.html). It uses similar terminology to Azure CLI. For your specific command, I believe [`checkExistenceById`](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-resource/latest/Resources.html#checkExistenceById) is what you are looking for.

Follow the [installation instructions](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/index.html) and learn the docs to see how to integrate the SDK into your app:

```
$ npm install azure-arm-resource
```